# How to make font a bit larger or smaller in a TextView relative to its size

Tags: android, textview

How can I make the font size in a `TextView` a bit larger or smaller relative to the current font size?

I see many people using hard-coded font size values like `15sp` but I'd like to avoid that because I want to be independent of the current font size. Instead, I was thinking of multiplying the font size by 1.2 to make it larger and by 0.8 to make it smaller, e.g. like this:

```
// make font larger
float size = textView.getTextSize()*1.2;
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, size);
```

Still, I'm wondering if this is the best way to do it because it looks a little awkward. That's why I'd like to ask if there's a more convenient way to make the default `TextView` a bit larger or smaller without hard-coding values like `15sp`...

***EDIT***

I should add that I'm creating everything programmatically. I'm not using XML. So the `TextView` is created like this:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(context);
```

By doing it like this, `tv` will use Android's default font settings. Now I want to make the font in `tv` larger or smaller, programmatically in Java.

Answer (score 1):

`sp` values are used for text. The SP stands for "scalable pixels". The benefit of using the `sp` is that it would scale according to the user's preferences.

I would suggest not do any calculations manually. The value that `textView.getTextSize()` will return will essentially be of a "density-independent pixels" (for *textSize* will be `sp`). That value will most probably come from your theme.

Using *density-independent pixels* is the proper way (or autosizing which still uses `dp` or `sp`). What you are trying to achieve will be messy and you will have no idea how it will scale on runtime. Using the "hardcoded" values such as `15sp` it won't stop from the text from scaling according to the font size but on the contrary, it will be calculated accordingly. To give you an example, `15sp` will translate as such:

**For 100% font size:**

- **ldpi**      11.25px
- **mdpi**      15.00px
- **hdpi**      22.50px
- **xhdpi**     30.00px
- **xxhdpi**    45.00px

**For 75% font size:**

- **ldpi**      8.44px
- **mdpi**      11.25px
- **hdpi**      16.88px
- **xhdpi**     22.50px
- **xxhdpi**    33.75px

What you can do is use Autosizing into Textview.

To use auto-sizing you will need to convert your textview from:

```xml
<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="24sp" />
```

To:

```xml
<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="24sp"
    app:autoSizeMinTextSize="16sp"
    app:autoSizeStepGranularity="1sp"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
```

Programmatically:

```kotlin
TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration(
    textView,
    16, // min
    24, // max
    1, //granularity step
    TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP
)
```

The above means that:

- Minimum Text size is 16sp.
- Maximum Text size is 24sp.
- If the text size is not either of the max or min, then it will scale up or down by `1sp`. So all the available values will be `16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24`.

**Note:** To use AutoSize in TextView, ensure that you don't use `wrap_content` as it could lead to issues. I would suggest using a hardcoded value or if you are using ConstraintLayout to constraint it with percent, or actual constraints that restrict the size of the view.

Read more:

1. [Support different pixel densities](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities)
2. [Autosizing TextViews](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview)
3. [Making the most of TextView auto-sizing on Android by Nick Rout](https://medium.com/over-engineering/making-the-most-of-textview-auto-sizing-on-android-a39f71b6f3af)
4. [Calculator for DPI](https://pixplicity.com/dp-px-converter)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not using XML but everything is created programmatically. See my edit.

Comment: @Andreas I edited my answer with a Kotlin example of doing that.

Comment: Thanks, but this also use hard-coded values like 16 and 24. I'd like to avoid hard-coded values completely and have everything relative to the default font size.

Comment: Added explanation why I think that's a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Override `attachBaseContext()` of (base)activity and set there fontScale

```
override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context?) {
        val config =  Configuration()
        config.setToDefaults();
        config.fontScale = Random.nextFloat()*2;  // Here Goes scale value for 
        val context = newBase?.createConfigurationContext(config);
        super.attachBaseContext(context);
}
```

In the example I made it scale randomly every time, you can save somewhere needed scale value and set it here.

```
    btnChangeSize.setOnClickListener {
        recreate()
    }
```

Will make this function call and all texts will be scaled as you wanted

Comment: Won't this scale the font of all my views? I just want to scale the font size of a single view.

Comment: Yes, it will change on all views.